# Bootstrap CSS - getting text to apopear on one line in grid container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navbar with a grid inside of it. I need to have the text appear on one line. As you can see from this screenshot, "Cryptocurrencies / Markets" and "Market Cap" and volume take up multiple lines. I want the text to only take up one line. See attached screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of my page]

I've tried changing the col-sm-x classes but no luck. I can't get everything to line up on one line. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>@yield('meta_title') | @lang('constants.WEBSITE_NAME')</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type="text/css">

/* navbar */
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
/* Title */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
/* Link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
}
/* Caret */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #777;
    border-bottom-color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #333;
    border-bottom-color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #555;
    border-bottom-color: #555;
}
/* Mobile version */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #DDD;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #DDD;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #777;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
          color: #333;
    }
}
.navbar-top {
padding-left:150px;
font-size:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar mobile navbar-default visible-xs">


                            <div class="navbar-header navbar-top">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="color:#fff"><strong>Cryptocurrencies</strong> 1000 / Markets 1000</div>
                                                                    <div class="col-sm-5" style="color:#fff">
                                                                    <strong>Market Cap</strong>:$263,920,404,123 <strong>24h Vol</strong>:$15,360,994,812
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="col-sm-3">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit ICO</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Login</button>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </nav>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to include a width and margin on that div...

```
.navbar-top {
  padding-left: 150px;
  font-size: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 92%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And on your `.row` div add `align-items-center`

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I got the ext to show up on one line but I also want the buttons to line up on the same row as well. This is what I get now: https://ibb.co/dn71Rd

Comment: Take a look at this Codepen - https://codepen.io/fencepencil/pen/Pavqyp?editors=1100

Comment: Happy to help 